# Menu bar stops working on M1 MacBook Air

Tags: macos, big-sur, menu-bar

When running Big Sur on an M1 MacBook Air, the menu bar stops working and is completely unresponsive.

All other areas of the screen work normally.

The setup is M1 MacBook Air running in clamshell mode, connected to an external display.

Comment: Try restarting/booting in safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

This only seems to affect MacBooks running in clamshell mode (that is, lid is closed) and connected to an external display.

I don't have a fix, but opening the lid briefly and closing it again re-enables the menu bar as a workaround.